# We can't bring in a list of "Liked Videos" through YouTube Data API (v3)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

We can't get a list of “Liked videos" from a particular user's channel. 
( ex - channelID: [UCSeKu-qBs2F9eBPUUSB5JQ](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSeKuu-qBs2F9eBPUUSB5JQ))
[image]
[contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.likes not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgXrA.png)

Attempt to import contentDetails.releasedPlaylists.likes via "Channels: list" but cannot be imported. The user's "Liked videos" is open to the public.

Comment: Have you tried checking the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters)? I think you are looking for `myRating`?.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 What I want to find is a list of other users' liked videos.

Comment: Through the graphical interface of YouTube you can't access "Liked videos playlist" of anybody. Maybe people can allow access to others to access their "Liked videos playlist" but it seems clear for privacy concerns that it is disabled by default.